# Log4j2 XML substitute variable from yaml file

Tags: xml, spring, yaml, log4j2

In a log4j2 xml file, is it possible to pull in a variable from a yaml file in the same directory? I basically need to display the spring.application.name in the xml, but I want to pull it in externally instead of hardcoding into the properties. I cannot use environment variables either.

XML for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>

<Properties>
    <Property name="logPattern">%p | ${spring.application.name} | %-25.25F:%-5L| %d </Property>
</Properties>

<Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
        <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
```

The hope is to pull the application name from the yaml file below:

```
spring: 
  application: 
    name: myAppName
```

The reason I want to use a defined "app name" instead of just a class name, is because I am working with microservices that incorporate many different jars, and it would be more beneficial to reference an app name instead.

Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance.